# Internal Compiler Error: System.InvalidCastException in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

Just started getting this compiler error:

```
Internal compiler error. See the console log for more information. output 

was:
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.

  at Mono.CSharp.PendingImplementation.BaseImplements (System.Type iface_type, System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi, System.Reflection.MethodInfo& base_method) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.PendingImplementation.VerifyPendingMethods (Mono.CSharp.Report Report) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.TypeContainer.EmitType () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.RootContext.EmitCode () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Compile () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I was casting a component to an interface type, which was working fine (compiling and working right at runtime). I did the same in another method and this started, I quickly reverted my changes to the method and this error continues. I am honestly not sure how to resolve it, and google was not bringing up a whole lot of useful information.

Unity 4.6.3

Let me know if you need more information. Or if this is the wrong place to ask for assistance. Any ideas?

Edit: Going through and systematically removing my casts from Component to IPlayerObject (which is an interface).

Comment: Any idea what code is causing it? At all? without a sample it will be hard to help

Comment: I have absolutely no clue. I even reverted back to code from a couple hours ago and it's still throwing the error. I was making changes to several classes throughout the program, checking for compiler errors along the way. Here is the cast I have been doing for the interface:             IPlayerObject playerObject = (IPlayerObject)e.HitObject.GetComponent(typeof(IPlayerObject));

Comment: I take it you rebuilt and everything as well?

Comment: Just tried that, did not think building in VS for unity would be effective. It pointed out an Interface implementation error. Resolving that error fixed the internal Compiler Error that was thrown in unity. The implementation must have not been there when I committed a couple hours ago and I must have recently broken it as well. Thanks

Comment: No problem. I would *always* use VS given the option (and do for my Unity development) :)